# Adding plugin to Aloha Editor

Tags: plugins, font-size, aloha-editor

Hello I am trying to add Font size plugin to Aloha Editor, however I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: Aloha.settings.plugins is undefined

**EDIT:**
By doing the following I was able to fix the problem:

```
<script src="Scripts/aloha/lib/require.js"></script>

<script>
    Aloha.settings = {
    locale: 'en',
    plugins: {}
</script>
<script src="Scripts/aloha/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/ui,common/format,common/highlighteditables,common/link,community/fontsize"></script>
```

Aloha.settings now has an empty plugins object before the plugins are actually loaded.
My problem is now more specific to the plugin I am trying to use. I don't know which settings to specify in the plugins: {} bracket.

The plugins im trying to use can be found here:
https://github.com/jstrouse/Aloha-Plugin-FontSize 
https://github.com/deliminator/Aloha-Plugin-Colorselector
The latter is linked to directly from the official page:
http://aloha-editor.org/guides/plugins.html

Comment: do you have a live version of that page?

Comment: Sorry, no. My problem has change slightly though. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks.